# How to apply a running window to a simulink signal using embedded matlab function?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to apply a moving window to the signal of my Simulink model using embedded Matlab function.  But whenever I try to divide the signal in time frames, it is always showing to have 1 element. Please suggest how to apply a running window to such signals.

Comment: Why do you want to use a matlab function block? I think other solutions ae simpler. What did you already try?

Comment: So far I have only tried only the Matlab function block. Don't know abt any other methods. Please suggest some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a MATLAB function block might not be the best choice. Here is a simple implementation of a moving average filter. Add, Sin and Noise on the left generate an example signal. The mux in the centre is used to insert the new element. The Variable Selector is used to drop the oldest element. In my case I used a workspace variable N for the window size. When really using this I recommend to wrap everything into a subsystem and make it a mask parameter.

[image]

Comment: I have used your way and it works fine.Can I use the data of one window at a time?? I want to calculate upon one window at a time,the next window at the next.How can I do so??? Please help.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, the code is calculating one window at a time.

Comment: At last I got my solution using your code.What I was asking that if I could do other calculations using the data in one window,which I was able to do,This code sure was helpful.

Comment: @Daniel will you please explain which block is in the center of memory block and variable selector block? which says "zeros(N)"?

Comment: IC for initial condition : https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/ic.html